# Getting Quickbooks Error 3301

Tags: .net, quickbooks, qbfc

I have a Quickbooks integration that has been working for some time (years)

I am recently getting error 
3301

```
Cannot perform this request unless an interactive QuickBooks user is logged in
```

Of course, the first thing I did was make all the users get out so I can delete the certificate and re-certify the app making sure that its marked to allow regardless and that the correct user was chosen.

This did not change anything.

I can in fact log on to QB and then start the process, so the error message does seem to be accurate. I just dont understand why I am getting it. The RUN REGARDLESS option on the certificate should prevent this message.

The bulk of the program is running reports and parsing them out so I can do calculations w/ the numbers.

I have done many of these integrations, and have never had this particular problem. Maybe Im missing something...

I can not find anything on the web that talks about 3301. Does anyone have some ideas on what might be causing this?

TYIA

greg

Comment: Is an interactive QuickBooks user logged in?

Comment: thats the issue. If on one is logged in , i get the message. But the app is certified to run unattended.  I can, as i mentioned above, log in and watch it and it works fine. the issue is it SHOULD be able to run unattended.

Comment: My suspicion here would be that Intuit changed something which now requires that report to be run interactively only. What report is it? What year/version/edition of QuickBooks? What does your request look like?
 What does the full response look like? You're not really providing enough detail here for anyone to help you.